# seperate objects with simular id in array into new array(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

If i have an array of objects

```
var myArray = []
```

Populated by

```
var myObject = { 
id: 1,  
name: 'example'
}
```

Lets say 'myArray' has 6 'myObjects', half of them share the same id, i want a function that seperates 'myObjects' by id, so that i can pass it them on to another function that needs the id to be separated.

there is a rythme to the myArray data.

example of 2*3 (6) 'myObjects' where half share a similar id: [id:1, id:2, id:3, id:1, id:2, id:3]

i want that into 3 arrays. [id:1, id:1] [id:2, id2] [id:3, id:3]

How can i go about doing this in simple and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

plain JS

```
var groupedById = arr.reduce((map,obj) => {
    (map[obj.id] || (map[obj.id] = [])).push( obj );
    return map;
});
var itemsWithSameId = Object.keys( groupedById ).map(id => groupedById[id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal with a temporary object as reference to the item for the grouped id.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.id]) {
        this[a.id] = [];
        result.push(this[a.id]);
    }
    this[a.id].push(a);
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash and it's [_.groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) method. Something like this:

```
const sorted = _.groupBy(myArray, 'id');
```

(not tested btw)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, output is array of arrays.

```js
var myArray = [
{id: 1,name: 'example'},
{id: 2,name: 'example'}, 
{id: 3,name: 'example'}, 
{id: 1,name: 'example'},
{id: 2,name: 'example'}, 
{id: 3,name: 'example'}, 
{id: 1,name: 'example'},
{id: 2,name: 'example'}, 
{id: 3,name: 'example'}
]

var tempObj = {};

$.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
  if (!tempObj[value.id]) {
    tempObj[value.id] = [];
  }
  tempObj[value.id].push(value);
});

finalArray = []
$.each(tempObj, function(i, v) {
  finalArray.push(v);
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(finalArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not optimized, but working example:

```
var array = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];

var resultObj = {};
var resultArray = [];

array.forEach(function(x) {
  //get the id
  var id = x.id;
  //if id is unknown, add new key to resultObj
  if (!resultObj.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    resultObj[id] = [];
  }
  //add object to id
  resultObj[id].push(x);
});

//loop over resultObj keys
for (var key in resultObj) {
    if (resultObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    //push array to 2dArray
    resultArray.push(resultObj[key]);
  }
}

//show results
console.log(resultObj);//{1:[{id:1}, {id:1}], 2:[...], ...]}
console.log(resultArray);//[[{id:1}, {id:1}], [...], ...]
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zdtddc7f/

Answer (score 0):

this is a Vanilla JavaScript version, it can do with tidying up but it does the job.

All it does is loop your `array` of `objects`, for the first `loop` push the `id` of the `object` to a temporary `array` (to keep track of the `ids`) create a new `array` in `masterArr` with the `object` in, on every subsequent `loop` it checks to see if an entry with the same `id` exist and if it does adds it to the correct location otherwise creates a new `array` with the `object` and keeps track of the `id` in the `idArr` again.

```
function filterArray(arr) {     
  var masterArr = [], idArr = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      idArr.push(arr[i].id);
      masterArr.push([arr[i]]);
    } else {
      var idCheck = idArr.indexOf(arr[i].id);           
      if (idCheck > -1) {
        masterArr[idCheck].push(arr[i]);
      } else {
        idArr.push(arr[i].id);
        masterArr.push([arr[i]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return masterArr;
}
```

then you call it like this

```
var mappedArray = filterArray(myArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4x2boyw/